# How debug akka association porcess?

Tags: scala, akka, virtualbox, redhat

Here is a scenario:

1. I have packaged scala project with spray into jar file.
2. Launch jar file on RedHat 6.5 on Virtual Box (ip - 192.168.1.**38**)
3. Launch jar file on RedHat 6.5 on Virtual Box (ip - 192.168.1.**41**)
4. Everything works locally - I can send REST request to each virtual machine and get response.

**Problem**

Akka systems can not became to cluster. I run 192.168.1.**38** with default settings, but 192.168.1.**41** have an additional property - akka.cluster.seed-nodes which is set to `akka.tcp://mySystem@192.168.1.38:2551`. So I get:

```
[WARN] [12/09/2014 17:10:24.043] [mySystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-8] [akka.tcp://mySystem@192.168.1.41:2551/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FmySystem%40192.168.1.38%3A2551-0] Association with remote system [akka.tcp://mySystem@192.168.1.38:2551] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://mySystem@192.168.1.38:2551]].
```

No other errors or warning. Also how can I test akka association or print debug akka association settings?

Also can linux settings influence to akka association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably `iptables` is blocking particular port, if it's your test configuration just disable iptables.

```
service iptables save
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off

service ip6tables save
service ip6tables stop
chkconfig ip6tables off
```

If it will not help try to check you `SELinux` configuration using command `getenforce` and the same for test purposes you can completely disable it. [SELinux manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux.html)

In case of your `application.conf`, try using  following configuration for each node:

```
 akka {

  log-dead-letters = on
  loglevel = "debug"

  actor
  {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  extensions = ["akka.contrib.pattern.ClusterReceptionistExtension"]

  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      port = 6001
    }
  }
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://ActorSystem@192.168.1.38:6001",
      "akka.tcp://ActorSystem@192.168.1.41:6001"
    ]
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
  }
}
```

All the logs related to the cluster nodes are logged as `info` but having `debug` log level in test environment is in general good idea.

When the second, node will join the cluster, you should notice following log:

```
INFO  [ActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [Cluster(akka://ActorSystem)]   - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ActorSystem@10.0.1.41:6001] - Marking node(s) as REACHABLE [Member(address = akka.tcp://ActorSystem@10.0.1.41:6001, status = Up)]
```

Cluster state could be also monitored using jmx `akka.Cluster` MXBean

```
{   "self-address": "akka.tcp://ActorSystem@10.0.1.82:6001",   "members": [     {       "address": "akka.tcp://ActorSystem@10.0.1.82:6001",       "status": "Up"     }   ],   "unreachable": [        ] }
```